# How to benchmark a xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin, benchmarking

I want to benchmark the perfomance for different devices in xamarin forms, does xamarin have some tool to that? or there is other tool that can mesure the perfomance of an app in different devices

Comment: What exactly are you trying to measure/compare?

Comment: You can do it with Visual Studio: MEnu "Analyse\Performance Profiler..."